# define, radio button change to auto drop down with loop

Tags: php, loops, radio-button, drop-down-menu

i looking for help... and hope of you kindly

I want to change my site language model from radio button to auto dropdown button using loop

This the languages

```
if ($lang=="en") {
//Pages
define ("Pages", "Pages") ;

}

if ($lang=="de") {
define ("Pages", "Seiten") ;
}
```

This the existing Radio button

```
                <td width="60%">Languange<b><BR />
                <?php 
                    if ($lang == 'en') {
                        print '<input type="radio" value="de" checked name="lang_" /> German&nbsp;&nbsp
                                <input type="radio" value="en" name="lang_" />English&nbsp';
                    }
                    else {
                        print '<input type="radio" value="de" name="lang_" />German&nbsp;&nbsp
                                <input type="radio" value="en" checked name="lang_" />English&nbsp';
                    }
                ?>
                </b></td>
```

and the Radio button above i want to change drop down button, i looking your help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am struggling to understand your question, but are you looking to do something like this? (I haven't tested this code yet)

```
<td width="60%">Languange<br />
    <select name="lang_">
    <?php
        $languages = array(
            'en'    =>  'English',
            'de'    =>  'German',
            'fr'    =>  'French',
        );

        foreach ($languages as $abrv => $language) {
            printf(
                '<option %s value="%s">%s</option>',
                $lang == $language ? 'selected' : '',
                htmlentities($abrv),
                htmlentities($language)
            );
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank You Mikuso, Maybe like this,..
if($lang_select == 'de')
 $languages = array(
            'Pages'    =>   'Seiten',
            'Bla..'    =>   'Bla..',

 ); //endarray

} elseif ($lang_select == 'fr')
{ 
 
 $languages = array (
            'Pages'    =>   '???',
            'Bla..'    =>   'Bla..',
} else
{ 
 
 $languages = array (
            'Pages'    =>   'Pages',
            'Bla..'    =>   'Bla..',
} ;

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this in PHP without refreshing the page. otherwise, you can use JavaScript to detect when the radio buttons are clicked, and then change the drop down appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I ever seen like this code, that i want to

```
function optionbox($boxname, $cssclass, $elementsarray, $cat_activ=1) {
    echo "<select name='$boxname' class='$cssclass'>";
    while (list($key,$value) = each($elementsarray)) {
        if ($key == $cat_activ) {               // Kategory ist actif 
            $SELECTED = "SELECTED";
        } else {
            $SELECTED = "";
        } //endif
        echo "<option $SELECTED value='$key'>$value</option>";
    } //endwhile
    echo "</select>";
}
```

but i am new to php..